# Understanding WSDL files. Two WSDL files for one web service

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

I am involved in consuming web service. The document I have given is two WSDL files. Due to the security reasons I cant post those files. I have to create a code to consume this web service. I dint have received credentials to call the service yet.

I have to completely rely on this WSDL files. following are the sample code snippet from the files.

WebService.wsdl

```
 <wsdl:message name:"createFunctionRequest”>
    <wsdl:part name=“ createFunctionRequest” element=“s1: createFunctionRequestMsg"
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:operation name:"createFunctionRequest”>
    <wsdl:input name=“ createFunctionRequest” message=“ins: createFunctionRequest"
 </wsdl:operation>
```

ThirdParty.wsdl

```
 <wsdl:message name:"FunctionCreated”>
    <wsdl:part name=“FunctionCreated” element=“s1: FunctionCreatedMsg"
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:operation name:"FunctionCreated”>
    <wsdl:input name=“FunctionCreated” message=“ins: FunctionCreated"
 </wsdl:operation>
```

My assumption is “ to call the createFunctionRequest I have to send a createFunctionRequestMsg to the web service. Then as a response I will receive  FunctionCreatedMsg. “ Is it correct?

I am trying to create mock web service using this wsdl file in SoapUI. But It dint sent the response since operation: createFunctionRequest dint have output field in it. In such case how can I combine these two files into one and mock the web service?.

Please Help me to understand this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is partially correct.

**Correct** -

> to call the createFunctionRequest I have to send a
>   createFunctionRequestMsg to the web service.

**Incorrect** -

> Then as a response I will receive FunctionCreatedMsg.

because the operation `createFunctionRequest` contains only `input` parameter, there is no `output` parameter. So you won't get any response back. This is an example of on-way web-service.What I understood is you are looking for an synchronous request-response web-service,your wsdl will become more like the one below.

You need to add the `output` variable in your wsdl operation -

```
     <wsdl:message "name:createFunctionRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="createFunctionRequest” element="s1: createFunctionRequestMsg"/>
 </wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message "name:FunctionCreated">
<wsdl:part name="FunctionCreated” element="s1:FunctionCreatedMsg"/>
</wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:operation "name:createFunctionRequest”>
    <wsdl:input name="createFunctionRequest" message="ins: createFunctionRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output name="FunctionCreated" message="ins: FunctionCreated"/>
 </wsdl:operation>
```

The other way would be to import the Thirdparty.wsdl in your Webservice.wsdl.So that you can get the message type.

Doing this you will be able to get the response in your SOAPUI.

If yours is an asynchronous service, where you need to callback `FunctionCreated` operations as the response of createFunctionRequest, then your wsdl will look different.Let me know if that is the case.

Comment: Hi Habin , Thanks for the response. The web service will send push messages to me. From the sequence diagram which i got as a part of the descriptions says that, as a response to “createFunctionRequest” I will get “FunctionCreated” response when ever a new function has been created in the server.

Comment: What I understand is that you are dealing asynchronous web service. Here it is well explained - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e15184/asynch.htm#WSCPT140 . Here the link for SOAPUI testing http://blog.soasuitehandbook.org/test-asynchronous-service-from-soapui-chapter-12/